# ClassCastException when trying to retrieve json node

Tags: java, json, unirest

I am receiving the following error when I try to store in a json response in a data store and then try to retrieve the particular json node from the response:

> Error Message: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode

I can see it is retrieving the response as I wanted, but it errors out when retrieving the node in the next line.

```
    public void hitEndpoint(String endpoint) {
        DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFactory.getScenarioDataStore();
        HttpResponse<String> httpResponse;
        String url = "xxx/xxx";
        try {
            httpResponse = Unirest.post(url)
                    .asString();
            dataStore.put("httpResponse", httpResponse);
        ...

    }

    public void RetrieveExampleNode(String endpoint){
        DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFactory.getScenarioDataStore();
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> httpResponse = (HttpResponse<JsonNode>) dataStore.get("httpResponse");
        String getExampleNode = httpResponse.getBody().getObject().getJSONArray("test").getJSONObject(0).get("example").toString();
       //error in the above line
    }
```

JSON trying to parse and currently retrieved by httpResponse in the above code:

```
{"test": [{"example": "2019-09-18T04:32:12Z"}, {"type": "application/json","other": {"name": Test Tester}}]}
```

Comment: So you are using unirest library, it would be good to point this out. I am confused because `getBody()` [returns](http://javadox.com/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java/1.4.7/com/mashape/unirest/http/HttpResponse.html) `JsonNode` and that [has no](http://javadox.com/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java/1.4.5/com/mashape/unirest/http/JsonNode.html) `getJSONObject` method??? What version are you using? Also what should you do is split `httpResponse.getBody().getJSONObject(0).get("example").toString();` to multiple lines and see what step causes exception (Or post whole stack trace where it is visible).

Comment: @Piro Just sorting out the stack trace. Unirest 1.4.9.Couldn't get the full stack trace but did your multiple line method. It fails in getbody()

Comment: Can you please post the actual JSON you're trying to parse?

Comment: @MrHadiSatrio {"test": [{"example": "2019-09-18T04:32:12Z"}, {"type": "application/json","other": {"name": Test Tester}}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClassCastException is thrown because in `hitEndpoint` method you are storing `HttpResponse<String>` to datastore so casting it to `HttpResponse<JsonNode>` in `RetrieveExampleNode` method is wrong!

Instead you should have `HttpResponse<JsonNode>` in the first place:

```
public void hitEndpoint(String endpoint) {
            DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFactory.getScenarioDataStore();
            HttpResponse<JsonNode> httpResponse;
            String url = "xxx/xxx"t;
            try {
                httpResponse = Unirest.post(url)
                        .asJson();
                dataStore.put("httpResponse", httpResponse);
    ...
}
```

See more in [Baeldung unirest guide](https://www.baeldung.com/unirest)

If you need to convert between `String` and `JsonNode` use `toString()` method and `JsonNode(String)` constructor.

Comment: Doing this will break my script, instead of changing to JsonNode, I can try to change the httpResponse<JsonNode> to httpResponse<String> but then it reds out gebody()

Comment: @BruceyBandit that is up to you, but you cannot handle `HttpResponse<JsonNode>` as `HttpResponse<String>` and vice versa, you have to pick one.

Comment: I am going to pick httpResponse<String> but the issue in that it reds out getObject: `String getExampleNode = httpResponse.getBody().getObject().getJSONArray("test").getJSONObject(0).get("example").toString();` How should this part be written?

Comment: @BruceyBandit `httpResponse.getBody()` returns String then. String has no `getObject()` method. If you need to work with body as both String and JsonNode you have to convert between them. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

please check the HttpResponse class package and cast the json object not array after that get the json object and get array in your response  :

```
     com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://shopName.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-04/orders.json").basicAuth("Api-Key", "Password").asJson();
   JSONObject myJSON = response.getBody().getObject();
```

I hope this will help other people as well :)